# gnome shell[31567]: clutter_actor_set_size: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed

Tags: centos, filesystems, gnome, gnome-terminal, firewalld

Trying to start firewalld but getting this gnome error. I restarted gnome and gnome is active. i am using CentOS7.  I searched Google but wasn't much on this error.

```
gnome shell[31567]: clutter_actor_set_size: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
```

Also asked in #gnome Liberia.Chat before asking here.

Comment: gnome-shell output has no relation with firewalld.  Most likely you have a syntax error in your firewalld config if it isn’t starting.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/663961/117549)?